# ISNT Measurements using Circular Hough Transoformation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is it Possible to Find out Measurement of ISNT ( Inferior, Superior, Nasal, Temporal) Distances by Detecting Optic Cup and Optic Disc using Circular Hough Transformation from following Image? -

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over on the MathWorks file exchange. There is a function for [detecting circles using the Hough Transform](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4985-circle-detection-via-standard-hough-transform).  You should be able to calculate distances in pixels and translate those to whatever unit you wish, so long as you have a reference to go against.

I haven't personally used the function so I can't say if it is exactly what you need, but it's a place to start.